# How to union table with inner join in distance searching using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, union, latitude-longitude

Am creating a product page where buyer can only order from nearby stores based on sellers store coordinate and buyer coordinate.
Everything is working fine except the search function when i search product it show all item stored in database, but i don't want it that way i also want to use MYSQL distance on search query.

In MYSQL query for search am using union to search both sellers and product. My problem is how i can implement both MYSQL `UNION, INNER JOIN` and `DISTANCE` all together. Below is my table structure.

product

```
id   | podkey  | price  | name     | store_key  | owner_pkey  | pod_status
-----|---------|--------|----------|------------|-------------|------------
 1   | 1ab2    | 100    | Dog      | sk76n      | MBYUU00     | 1
 2   | 0kb2    | 180    | Cat      | sk76n      | MBYUU00     | 1
 3   | 5ab1    | 101    | Doggy    | sk76n      | MBYUU00     | 1
 4   | maf1    | 60     | Bird     | sk16b      | MBYUU00     | 1
 5   | baf0    | 90     | Dog      | sk78x      | KLYUP07     | 1
```

store

```
id  | skey  | ownerkey | lat        | lng        | name
----|-------|----------|------------|------------|----------------- 
1   | sk76n | MBYUU00  | 2.922597   | 101.661896 | Cyberjaya store
2   | sk16b | MBYUU00  | 3.7384847  | 107.893837 | Puchong store
3   | sk78x | KLYUP07  | 7.64874646 | 883.893839 | My only store
```

Owners

```
id  | name    | owner_key 
----|---------|--------------
1   | peter   | MBYUU00
2   | john    | KLYUP07
```

This below what is what am currently using to display items on page and is working

```
SELECT p.id, p.podkey, p.price, p.name, p.store_key, p.pod_status, s.id, s.skey, s.ownerkey, s.name, o.id, o.name, o.owner_key,
SQRT(POW(69.1 * (s.lat - :getBuyerLat), 2) + POW(69.1 * (:getBuyerLon - s.lng) * COS(s.lat / 57.3), 2)) AS distance
FROM product p

INNER JOIN Owners o
ON p.owner_pkey = o.owner_key

INNER JOIN store s
ON s.skey = p.store_key

WHERE p.pod_status = 1
HAVING distance <= 5
```

The below query is what i tried on the search but it doesn't return anything or show any error

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
    SELECT 'products' as type, pod_status AS stat, name AS name, price AS price, store_key AS skey, NULL AS distance FROM product p
    UNION
    SELECT 'sellers' as type, 1 AS stat, name AS name, NULL AS price, NULL AS skey, NULL AS distance FROM Owners o
    UNION
    SELECT 'outlets' as type, 1 AS stat, name AS name, NULL AS price, skey AS skey,
    SQRT(POW(69.1 * (s.lat - :getBuyerLat), 2) + POW(69.1 * (:getBuyerLon - s.lng) * COS(s.lat / 57.3), 2)) AS distance
    FROM store s
) sfoo
INNER JOIN store sj
ON sj.skey = sfoo.store_key
WHERE sfoo.name LIKE %dog% AND sfoo.stat = 1 HAVING distance <= 5
```

Please can anyone assist me here is MCVE http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/afaf39/2/0

Comment: @Strawberry, thanks for the update i will create one

Comment: @Strawberry please refer to this link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/afaf39/2/0

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this is confusing.  Only outlets will be returned from the subquery, because `distance` is `NULL` for the other two.  No outlets have "dog" in their name.

Seems pretty simple.  The first query has nothing to do with the second because the filtering criteria are different.

Comment: @Peter - Add a `PRIMARY KEY` to each table; add other indexes as needed.  Don't use `(m,n)` on `FLOAT`.  Use `VARCHAR` instead of `CHAR`.